# stupid questions how to define a function of 2 variables

Tags: functions

I have the code which works

```
g[x_, y_] := f[x] + f[y]
```

But then I tried

```
vavg (distance_, time_) := distance/time
```

And then I get the error 
Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "distance_,time_)".

I am stuck lol :( Pls help ?

Comment: try `vavg[distance_, time_] := distance/time`  just like the code you said worked.

Comment: thank you sir . i could kiss your feet for helping !

Comment: Thanx to this question I got banned and i cannot ask anymore ! Thanx quora

Answer (score 2):

As Mr. Nasser said the solution is

vavg[distance_, time_] := distance/time

Thank you !